# extract variable label from a dataframe to assign to a variable in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df_old), that has a variable label and I want to extract the labels and put it into respective variables in another dataframe (df_new).
In a loop, I'd like to use this code but it doesn't work

```
  attr(  df_new[ , j] , "label") <- attr( df_old[ , j] , "label")
```

That doesn't work, so I've got around it doing it this way

```
Tmp <- data.frame( df_old[ , j ] )
names(Tmp) <- "Var"
attr(  df_new[ , j] , "label") <- attr( Tmp$Var , "label")
```

Is there a way to do it in one step?

UPDATE : include example df_old and df_new

```
df_old <- structure(list(A1_1 = structure(c(1, 3, 2, 1, 6, 1, 5, 7, 1, 
                                  1), label = "Use Facebook", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 1L, labels = c(`Every day` = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                   `A few times a week` = 2, `A few times a month` = 3, `Once a month` = 4, 
                                                                                                                                                                   `Every few months` = 5, `Less often` = 6, `I never do this activity` = 7
                                  ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), A1_2 = structure(c(1, 
                                                                                                              4, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 7, 1, 6), label = "Use Instagram", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 1L, labels = c(`Every day` = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        `A few times a week` = 2, `A few times a month` = 3, `Once a month` = 4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        `Every few months` = 5, `Less often` = 6, `I never do this activity` = 7
                                                                                                              ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), A1_3 = structure(c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          1, 2, 7, 7, 6, 1, 7, 2, 1), label = "Use TikTok", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 1L, labels = c(`Every day` = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 `A few times a week` = 2, `A few times a month` = 3, `Once a month` = 4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 `Every few months` = 5, `Less often` = 6, `I never do this activity` = 7
                                                                                                                                                                                          ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), label = "TvTPQ2_0.sav")

df_new <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = ncol(df_old), nrow = nrow(df_old)  )) 
names(df_new) <-  paste0( names(df_old) ,"_new")
```

Comment: Can you please include a small example of what your `df_new` and `df_old` look like, either using `dput()` or a built-in data set? It would make it easier for us to run your examples.

Comment: added example in question. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `for` loop or any of the apply family of functions to transfer the attributes.

```
df_new[] <- Map(function(x, y) {attr(x,"label") <- attr(y,"label");x}, df_new, df_old)
```

check the attributes -

```
sapply(df_old, attr, 'label')

#          A1_1            A1_2            A1_3 
# "Use Facebook" "Use Instagram"    "Use TikTok" 

sapply(df_new, attr, 'label')
#      A1_1_new        A1_2_new        A1_3_new 
# "Use Facebook" "Use Instagram"    "Use TikTok"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `labelled::var_label()` to both extract and assign the labels:

```
library(haven)
library(labelled)

var_label(df_new) <- unlist(var_label(df_old))

attr(df_new$A1_1_new, "label")
# "Use Facebook"
```